# Cassandra behavior during multiple identical bulk imports

Tags: cassandra

I'm using the Datastax driver to convert some csv file into SSTable. I then push it into cassandra using the `sstableloader` command. I observed a behavior I am struggling to explain, here is the database after the first bulk import:

```
 sentence_id | text
-------------+--------
           5 |  fffff
           1 |  bbbbb
           8 |  iiiii
           0 |  aaaaa
           2 |  ccccc
           4 |  eeeee
           7 |  hhhhh
           6 |  ggggg
           3 |  ddddd
```

I then push some new data into my table, overwriting one row:

```
session.execute("insert into sentences (sentence_id, text) values (%s, %s)", (100, "hehehe"))
session.execute("insert into sentences (sentence_id, text) values (%s, %s)", (1, "hehehe"))
```

Here is the table now:

```
 sentence_id | text
-------------+--------
           5 |  fffff
           1 | hehehe
           8 |  iiiii
           0 |  aaaaa
           2 |  ccccc
           4 |  eeeee
           7 |  hhhhh
         100 | hehehe
           6 |  ggggg
           3 |  ddddd
```

Now if I do a new bulk import, I would expect the row of sentence_id 1 to be changed, yet nothing happen. In order for the data to be replaced I need to regenerate the SSTable before the import.

Any insight on what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sstable loader will take the data in the sstable and transfer it exactly as is to the replicas.

The `[1, bbbbb]` cell was written originally with a timestamp of when it was inserted. This timestamp is included when transferred with sstableloader.

When you do an insert the `[ 1, hehehe]` cell into the memtable (or a different sstable if its flushed) its timestamp is "now".

When you do a `SELECT` it will merge these cells and since there are conflicts, it will use the one thats inserted most recently (last write wins). Eventually when the data is compacted the `[1, bbbbb]` cell will not be copied and will cease to exist.